# How do you apply a discount code to the entire order amount in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am creating a form for ordering an unlimited amount of a customized product (as shown in the picture). [image]

I am trying to create a Discount Code (ANT20) that will take 20% off of the ENTIRE FORM TOTAL (not per item since the amount of items created is endless).  I understand the coding for creating the calculations, but as you can see, it does not understand the field name 'total'.  In fact, it doesn't understand any field names that I have attempted to use.  I'm shooting in the dark because there is no way to find the actual field name of 'subtotal', or 'amount due', etc.

[image]

This has to be an easy fix.  I can't imagine the coders creating a sales form that cannot have a % of the entire order being taken off.  Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options for applying discounts to the entire order amount in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

1. Add additional fees and specify a negative percentage for a fixed discount amount.

   [image]
2. Calculate the order subtotal before the discount using a calculation, and apply the discount to this subtotal.  In your case the subtotal calculation would be `=AddYourMeals.Sum(Total)`, and the discount calculation would be:

   `=if CouponCode = "ANT20" then -0.2 * AddYourMeals.Sum(Total) else 0`.

While you can access the order subtotal using this calculation, `=Order.OrderAmount`, you cannot apply a discount based on this amount because the discounts reduce the order amount.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I was able to make it work by using the =Order.OrderAmount label in my calculation.  Thanks again!